# Is it correct to use "yonder" as equivalent to "those"/"these"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I want to write: "The methods can be divided according to the theories underlying the process and also differ on the statistical methods to evaluate *those* theories." Would it be correct to use *yonder* instead of *those* in this sentence to refer to a word used in the first part of the sentence --> *theories*? On the other hand I am not even sure if *those* is correct or if any I had to use *these*. I am always confused about the their difference.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Wait, why do you want to use "yonder"? And no, it's not used as a linguistic pronoun, it [was, a long time ago] used as a locative adverb, meaning "not *these* apples, not even *those* apples, but *thoooose* apples, *way over there*".

Comment: I concur: do not use *yonder* here.  I conjecture aldorado speaks some other language, which is why he wants to use *yonder*.

Comment: @DanBron I am not a native speaker, yet I did not know about the meaning - it was suggested to my by a translation program and looked like a synonym. Should I delete the question? Should such questions better be asked in the english learner stack exchange? And most important - If yonder is completely wrong - is these or those the correct word?

Comment: pretty much no one uses "yonder", except in certain dialects and writing such as novels

Comment: Sorry, I didn't consider that you might have English as a second language. I thought you were a native speaker trying (for some strange reason) to "jazz up" a report just for the sake of it.  To answer your question, I would say "*The methods can be divided according to the theories underlying the process, and also by the statistical methods used to evaluate them.*" (Sorry, I know that doesn't help you understand "these" vs "those".)

Comment: @DanBron Well thank you for the answer anyways - it helps - and no need to apologize: "Jazzing up" my report was exactly my intention ;) - As a non-native speaker one is tied to a limited set of synonyms and I use these/those a little to often. I was therefor looking for an alternative.

Comment: @sgroves Whilst 'yonder' is not part of everyday speech, it is the sort of word I would occasionally introduce in order to add variety and expression; especially since there is no obvious modern equivalent.

Comment: @ws2 i agree, and i do the same. regardless, i stand by my previous comment.

Comment: @Dan Bron OP's usage (and yours, if you're suggesting 'yonder apples' by 'thoooose apples') is not the adverb incarnation but the determiner. See FF's answer.

Comment: *Yonder* is deprecated in technical writing. Don't even go there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think non-native speakers would probably be well advised not to use ***yonder*** in *any* contexts (though as a native speaker myself I'm okay with *yonder=afar, over there* and ***yon***=those, that).

From oxforddictionaries online:

> [***yonder***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yonder)
>    ADVERB - ARCHAIC or DIALECT
>    *At some distance in the direction indicated; over there:*
>
> DETERMINER - ARCHAIC or DIALECT
>    *That or those (used to refer to something situated at a distance)*
>
> [***yon***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yon)
>    DETERMINER & ADVERB - LITERARY or DIALECT
>    *Yonder; that*

---

OP's example sentence is at least clumsy, if not ungrammatical. But so far as the *these/those* choice is concerned, both are perfectly acceptable in that/this context.

Comment: You might get away with saying "yonder buildings" but theories are never "over there in the distance".

Comment: @Oldcat: When I say I'm "okay" with these words, that doesn't imply I'd be likely to use them myself (except facetiously). Just that I'm sufficiently familiar with them that it doesn't seem particularly odd to encounter *other people* using them "naturally". But since it would be virtually impossible for a non-native speaker to use such words naturally, I'd practically *always* think it was an "error" if they used them.

Comment: +1 *Yon* and *yonder* represent a degree of spatial deixis that is no longer distinguished in most dialects of English (including the major standard dialects). If it's farther than *here* these days, it's *there*; you need to add words to distinguish more than that.

Comment: @bye: That's true, but [*the wide blue yonder*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wide+blue+yonder&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwide%20blue%20yonder%3B%2Cc0) is a relatively recent addition to "normal" usage. Though I guess I'd have to admit it's always a bit "facetious", 'cos so few of us are likely to use the word *yonder* naturally any more.

Comment: As someone who uses yonder natively, I'm all for people using it more often :-)

Comment: *Yonder* is **not** recommended for technical writing, which is what the text in question is.